# Show/Hide div based on another div's state without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show/hide 'link2' based on the state of the div. If it's open, hide link2, if it's closed, show link2.

both link1 and link2 trigger a close or open for the panel div.
Since I am using sessions to remember the state of the div, I want the corresponding link to show as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/9kUA5/

```
$('#panel').toggleClass('hidden', sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible') != 'true');
$('#flip, #flip_slip').click(function() {
    $('#panel').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible', $('#panel').hasClass('hidden'));
});
$('#flip_slip')[ $('#panel').is(':visible') ? "hide" : "fadeIn" ]();
```

html:

```
<div id="panel">
    test
   <div id="flip">link1</div>        
</div>  
<div id="flip_slip">link2</div>
```

EDIT:

example, if I click on link1 -> panel div fades ou -> link2 appears
since the session saves the state of panel div, on page refresh, link2 should be visible

Comment: please clearify what you need to have, it is so confusing

Comment: i want to click on link1 so it collapses the panel div, and link2 should then appear. And when i refresh the page, if the panel div is collapsed, then link2 should be there

Comment: ' when i refresh the page, if the panel div is collapsed, then link2 should be there' that seems to be working in your example.. hmm. is this what your looking for http://jsfiddle.net/9kUA5/5/?

Comment: YES! exactly that. if you put it as an answer ill accept it!

Answer (score 0):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/qd99Q/) with pretty simplified code.
*jQuery code*

```
$(function () {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible')===null){
        sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible', 'false');//initiate it for the first time
    };
    checkSessionStorage(); //call it to change the #panel display  

    $('#flip_slip,#flip').click(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible', (sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible') == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false')); //change the sessionStorage
        checkSessionStorage(); //call it to change the #panel display
    });
    function checkSessionStorage() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible') == 'true') {
            $('#panel').slideDown();
            $('#flip_slip').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('#panel').slideUp();
            $('#flip_slip').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't save the session, i know how to do that

Comment: it doesn't save the session. if I close the div it should stay closed on refresh